# Making custom libraries permanently visible for all future projects in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, settings, libraries

I was wondering if there was a way to create my own custom library , that would be visible for all future projects, and not just the current one ?
The library is supposed to be just a simple header file (.h) with all the libraries I need to work with already included in it. I've tried searching the web for a way to do it, but I had no luck in finding such a way. If anyone knows how to, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make your own `library`, you can follow these general steps;

Let's say you want to make a library `mlib`

1. First of all create an `Interface` of your library: `mylib.h`
2. Implement your library in `mylib.c`
3. Compile your `c` file and your will get `object fiile` with extention `.o` in linux that can be linked with programs that want to use our library code
4. Now you can include your header in your new program where you want to use your library and provide link of your `object` excuteable to compiler when compiling your program.

   #include

   // rest of your program

now for compiling

```
 clang -o myprogram myprogram.c -lmylib
```